# Is there a better 'rails' way of making this rename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Got this ActiveRecord puzzle, and no one can figure out a better method of extracting the table "`students`" from self (self is Student).

```
def self.all
  p self                  # = Student
  Database::Model.execute("SELECT * FROM #{self.to_s.downcase + "s"}").map do |row|
    self.new(row)
  end
end
```

Is this string manipulation the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken about your intentions, `Student.all` is what you would normally do.

If you're wondering about how `Student` becomes `"students"`, it basically involves `.class.name.downcase.pluralize` (if you keep the default table name). `pluralize` is quite a bit smarter than just adding `"s"` to a string.

Comment: ah - ok - it seems we have no rails methods available for this assignment - but I got some new methods to use when the time comes. Thanks!

Comment: `pluralize` is part of Rails; everything else I listed is standard Ruby.

Comment: BTW - I think we're supposed to replicate the activerecord method "all" using just sql commands.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding this method to a model to get a string reflecting the table name the model is using. Maybe.

If so, you could do this:

```
def self.all
  table_name
end
```

Or, because that's just effectively creating an alias, you could do:

`ModelName.table_name`